# Aliasing a subquery on WHERE

Tags: mysql

i have this example query assuming `MAX(id) = 100`

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) AND id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users)-50
```

i get from this query `ids` in range of `50 to 100` and it works as intended

but i want it to be shorter so i tried using alias like this

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) AS maxid AND id > maxid-50
```

but it doesnt work then i tried defining variable like this

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id < @x = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) AND id > @x-50
```

but got notice of

```
Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables
```

how to do the MAX(id) calculation once to save performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the variable before the query:

```
set @maxid = (select max(id) from users);
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE id > @maxid - 50 and id < @maxid;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hjFxiiP47U5K4gb23wxxhL/0).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to phrase your query which requires using the subquery only once:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) BETWEEN id + 1 AND id + 49;
```

That being said, in your first version I would expect that the MySQL optimizer would be smart enough to cache away the result of the max subquery, and thereby only compute it once.  So, I don't have a problem with your very first version.

Comment: Wouldn't this execute the subquery once per row in id?

Comment: @ZacharyOldham Nope.  For certain MySQL would execute it once, cache the results, and then reuse the cached value.